# How to remove \n from API response or get the response in appropriate JSON format when GET method is requested via APIView class

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

When I call ***Google's*** `Distance Matrix` API in postman I get a proper JSON response.

***API endpoint***

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=[API KEY]
```

***Response***

```
{
   "destination_addresses": [
      "New York, NY, USA"
   ],
   "origin_addresses": [
      "Washington, DC, USA"
   ],
   "rows": [
      {
         "elements": [
            {
               "distance": {
                  "text": "228 mi",
                  "value": 367435
               },
               "duration": {
                  "text": "3 hours 43 mins",
                  "value": 13385
               },
               "status": "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
```

But when I do the same in my DRF using ***APIView*** class I get some weird `\n` in response.

***APIView***

```
import requests
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class TestView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data={}
        data['destinations'] =[
            'Nashik+Maharashtra',
            'Mumbai+Maharashtra',
            'Nagpur+Maharashtra',
            'Malegaon+Maharashtra'
        ]
        data['origins'] = "Pune+Maharashtra"
        params ={
            "units":"metrix",
            "origins":data['origins'],
            "destinations":data['destinations'],
            "key":"AIzaSyDqf9R6mFSDrwqjM7iXv289o9KEdvEEmM8"
            }       

        response = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?", params)
        return Response(response.text)
```

***Response***

```
"{\n   \"destination_addresses\" : [ \"Nashik, Maharashtra, India\" ],\n   \"origin_addresses\" : [ \"Pune, Maharashtra, India\" ],\n   \"rows\" : [\n      {\n         \"elements\" : [\n            {\n               \"distance\" : {\n                  \"text\" : \"212 km\",\n                  \"value\" : 212479\n               },\n               \"duration\" : {\n                  \"text\" : \"4 hours 19 mins\",\n                  \"value\" : 15531\n               },\n               \"status\" : \"OK\"\n            }\n         ]\n      }\n   ],\n   \"status\" : \"OK\"\n}\n"
```

How can I get an appropriate JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

use `response.json()` instead of `response.text`

Answer (score 0):

```
res.json(JSON.parse(response));
```

And, In chrome Extension use
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en-US